# Сбились настройки кодировки русских букв

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea, soap, кодировка

возникла такая проблема: был создан веб-сервис SOAP, проблем с кодировкой не обнаруживалось, затем на его основе был создан другой проект, в нем начали возникать проблемы такие как неверная кодировка русских символов при тестировании в среде SOAP UI, а так же при записи данных в бд Postgresql. 
P.S. версия среды разработки, настройки кодировки, версия БД, версия SOAP UI не изменились, кодировка схем веб-сервиса UTF-8.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpSv1.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло вот что: на компьютере была установлена IDEA более ранней версии, загрузил одновременно этот проект в обеих IDE, cделал Build->Rebuild Project в IDE более ранней версии, затем её закрыл. В более свежей IDE появилось окно с предложением Reload Project, подтвердил. Проблема исчезла

Answer (score 0):

По хорошему лучше все писать в UTF-8, поэтому выставь и для property файлов UTF-8 и поставь галочку рядом. Далее проверь код, открой классы и посмотри какую кодировку показывает справа снизу в статусной строке, если не UTF-8, то кликаем там же (по кодировке), и выбираем UTF-8, если в коде есть строки с отличным от английского, то будет выдано диалоговое окно с предложением выполнить конвертацию или переоткрытие файла в выбранной кодировке (будут кнопки convert, reload) - нужно выбрать конвертацию, иначе файл переоткроется в UTF-8 и не английский контент приобретет вид как скрине выше. Если код не имеет юникодных символов, то файл переоткроется в UTF-8 кодировке. В итоге файл будет в нужной (UTF-8) кодировке, она же и будет значится в статусной строке.

Comment: к сожалению, ваш вариант мало чем мне помог. Помогло вот что: на компьютере была установлена IDEA более ранней версии, загрузил одновременно этот проект в обеих IDE, cделал Build->Rebuild Project в IDE более ранней версии, затем её закрыл. В более свежей IDE появилось окно с предложением Reload Project, подтвердил. Проблема исчезла.